# creating new template in crystal report , visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vba, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a new crystal report chart template, because I want my x-axis label to be vertical in the graph, and the existing templates in crystal report is not having that property. I tried with this link:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r1mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.btools.help.modeler.basic.doc/doc/tasks/reporting/creatingcrystaltemplates.html

But it is not clear to me. I am unable to fine the options what is mentioned in this.
So please can any one help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

That link is for creating *Report* Templates, not *Chart* Templates which is the one you want. I'm not sure if the process is different between VS and the standalone Crystal Reports Designer, but in the latter you can right-click on the chart and be presented with the options "Save as Template" and "Load Template". So just set up the chart how you want, save it to the DEFAULT FOLDER (this is important as Crystal might not read templates from any other folder), and you're done.

Tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQhMNuv-dro